# Android - Stack items next each other like tags

Tags: android

What I have :

[image]

What I wanna do :

[image]

Whenever I add item I want it to be placed next to the one before. If an element is at the end of the screen : I want it to be placed on the next line.
Something like `float: left` in **CSS**.

Comment: Please see edit for why it's not possible

Comment: What you're describing is commonly referred to as a FlowLayout. There are [several posts here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+flow+layout) already that might help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a layout like Java Swing FlowLayout. You have a few implementations of it around the web. This library looks promising, but I haven't tried it myself.

[Android FlowLayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

If this doesn't work for you, I'll edit and post a FlowLayout implementation I use. I can't do it now, since I'm away from my working machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your tags container to be eventually scrolling, then use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) and [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) and call on it `setSpanCount(3)`. Don't forget to set its orientation to `VERTICAL`

If yout won't ever need your items to be scrolling, then just use [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)

EDIT:

I have put together rough example which works in the way you want. You will probably need to take margins and padding into account as well, but it should serve to you as a basic idea how to do that.

```
public class TagLayout extends ViewGroup {

public TagLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TagLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TagLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public TagLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    int maxWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int count = getChildCount();

    int tagLeft = left,
        tagTop = top,
        tagRight = 0,
        tagBottom = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {

            tagRight = tagLeft + child.getMeasuredWidth();
            tagBottom = tagTop + child.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (tagRight > maxWidth) {
                tagLeft = left;
                tagRight = left + child.getMeasuredWidth();
                tagTop = tagBottom;
                tagBottom += child.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            child.layout(tagLeft, tagTop, tagRight, tagBottom);
            tagLeft = left;
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int count = getChildCount();
    int maxWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
            measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            width += child.getMeasuredWidth();
            if (height == 0) {
                height += child.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            if (width <= maxWidth) {
                continue;
            } else {
                width = 0;
                height += child.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
        }

    }
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}

}
```

Comment: Please see edit. It's not actually a grid, it's like float:left in css

Comment: Oh, first thing that came on my mind was using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` but it would't actually work I guess.
Then I would built a custom ViewGroup, but this one is far more complicated, you will have to override and implement both `onLayout` and `onMeasure` methods with your custom logic. I'm sorry I don't have time right now for any example, maybe somebody more experienced could write it without digging into it for a significant amount of time.

Comment: I ended up using FlowLayout library. Thanks for the effort though.