# How to set random number of TextView in layout in form of grid?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-gridview

I have some text from server. I want to show each text in a `TextView`.
Text length can be different. I want maximum three `TextView` in any row.
Help me on this. Which layout should I use & how to accomplish this?

[image: Check image for more info]

Comment: Try [this link(Variable span size)](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html). It will give an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a custom `ViewGroup` and override its measure and layout logic, or you can use nested `LinearLayouts` (vertically oriented parent with horizontally oriented rows).
You can always check the very bottom row for how many `TextViews` it does contain. If there will be three, just add another `LinearLayout` - as a next row.
The first solution will be harder to implement, but at the other hand it will be much more efficient (if done right of course).

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30373236/419449) you can find my approach to a kind of similar problem.
Also actually look at the flow layout linked in one other answer on the linked question. That might help you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your first solution more? 2nd solution will add three textview per line which is not expected.

Comment: @VivekSinha: why is it not expected?

Comment: Bcoz three is the maximum number of textView per line. One can can also have only one or two textView if a textView has longer text.

Comment: Got it..then you are actually solving very similar problem to the linked one.

Comment: Hi, how can I remove those arrows in flow layout?

Comment: @VivekSinha I haven't used FlowLayout myself - these arrows shown on the Github page are actually there once it is drawn?
Just look around in the repository. There might be some kind of configuration, or you can eventually fork the repository and disable the arrow drawing logic. I won't post more here, as it really goes beyond the scope of this question.